# Is logback only compatible with tomcat applications?

Tags: java, logging, logback

I am currently working on migrating some applications from log4j to logback. The tomcat applications I have migrated are all working fine with the new logback configurations (logback.xml) however the none tomcat application don't appear to be picking up the logback configs (everything is just being logged into the default logfile)

There is no warning about log4j appenders being missing so I am assuming it is not still trying to use log4j configs.

The dependencies I have for my logging are as follows (same as in the tomcat applications)

```
<!-- logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: _Is logback only compatible with tomcat applications?_ No. Show us how your application is run.

Comment: It is just a java  application running on a unix box.

Comment: How do you launch it?

Comment: It is started via a startup script.

Comment: First, why are you including both log4j and logback? I would remove the log4j dependency and make sure your code is using the slf4j logger manager.  Furthermore, logback-classic itself has native dependencies on slf4j-api and logback-core, so technically the only actual dependency you need here is the logback-classic one.

Comment: as mentioned, remove the log4j dependancy and replace it with a dependancy on slf4j-log4j12

Comment: I will give this a try ad let you all know. Thanks!

Comment: None of this made a difference :( Thanks though!

Comment: How do you package your application? What does the startup script look like? What does your logback.xml look like? Where do you put it?